# How disable gzip on azure function app?

Tags: .net, azure

The gzip for azure functions app is enabled by default, is there any way to disable it?

I tried to edit the web.config file but there is no place to access the file system on the server.

Comment: You want to edit `urlCompression` in the web.config to do it?

Comment: i don’t know anywhere else can achieve this

Comment: May be you could access `applicationhost.config` via Kudu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could edit [urlCompression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/urlcompression) in the `LocalSiteRoot/Config/applicationhost.config`  via Kudu Debug console(CMD).

[image]

```
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

> Compression in IIS 7.x  is configured with two .config file elements in the  space. The elements can be set anywhere in the IIS/ASP.NET configuration pipeline all the way from ApplicationHost.config down to the local web.config file.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/05/Builtin-GZipDeflate-Compression-on-IIS-7x).

Comment: i located the file, BUT i got following errors, seems Azure Functions App don't allow this.
409 Conflict: Could not write to local resource 'D:\local\Config\applicationhost.config' due to error 'Access to the path 'D:\local\Config\applicationhost.config' is denied.'.

Comment: ok, found the way, i need to add an applicationHost.xdt into the site root to replace the local root setting. thank you for giving me the hint

Comment: @RayH please mark this as answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I turned it off (in the response) by adding a custom response header in host.json.

```
{
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "customHeaders": {
                "Content-Encoding": "none"
            }
        }
    }
}
```